# Use Lib in Component

Tags: cakephp

I want use a *CustomLib* in my Component.
How can I do that?

I try `App::uses('Util','Lib')`, but doesn't work:

```
$number = $this->Util->sqlnum($number);
Error: Call to a member function sqlnum() on a non-object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With App::uses() you are only telling Cake where to find the class.
You still need to create the object yourself

```
$this->Util = new Util();
$number = $this->Util->sqlnum($number);
```

basis OOP.

The only case where you don't need to do that is when you are accessing methods statically.

```
public static function sqlnum($number) {}
```

and

```
$number = Util::sqlnum($number);
```

But if that is possible depends on your class and how the method works.

---

EDIT:
And to complete this: for model classes its different. You always use:

```
$MyModel = ClassRegistry::init('MyModel'); // never use `new MyModel()` here
```

and you don't need to App::uses() the class, as ClassRegistry does this itself.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. But I did some searching on the way back, the folks did not recommend using "new Object ()".